# name of curve of cluster of points of the form $(x,x^2...x^n)$ in $R^n$

Tags: reference-request

what is the name of the curve made up of the points $(x,x^2...x^n)$ in $\mathbb {R}^n$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$??

For example: in $\mathbb R^2$ it would just be a parabola.

Comment: I don't imagine it has a particular name?

Comment: I think it does.

Comment: http://www.nameacurve.com perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I was joking... (I was thinking star registry.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the 
[rational 
normal curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_normal_curve) of degree $n$.  ("Basically" because the usual
rational normal curve is $n$-dimensional projective space
and has an additional point at infinity.)

Answer (score 2):

The curve of this form is known as the [moment curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_curve).

Comment: Right $-$ indeed I see now that the Wikipedia page I linked to mentions that the
affine locus of the rational normal curve is called the moment curve.

Comment: I guess every curve has its moment.